# Why does open() never return?

Tags: c, serial-port, gnu-screen

I am operating in a Fedora environment, using c code to open a USB port to talk with a serial device.

For the most part, my program works fine. However, as part of testing, I regularly open a terminal window and run the screen command and then manually send commands to the serial device. That works fine as well, but afterwards, the port is no longer accessible to the c program.  I've closed the screen instance either with ctrl-a k, OR with ctrl-a d followed by the appropriate `sudo kill -9 <ID>`.  Afterwards there seems to be no evidence of the screen instance (`sudo lsof /dev/tty*` shows no "screen"), however, running my c program fails. As far as I can tell, the open(...) command just hangs.  The only way to restore connectivity is to remove and reinsert the USB cable to the device.

So,

- 1. Is there a better way to close the "screen" instance than the two I've been using?
- 2. Why would "open" not return?

Comment: Sounds like the usb device driver is not doing what it needs to do.

Comment: Eugene - If so, that's out of my control, no? Do you mean in the host or the device?

Comment: Can you check the serial port state settings with stty and set them back to that state when you are done?

Comment: @mike65535 I mean the device driver, but who knows. Anyway, is the behavior the same if you open the device by other means? If not, then maybe its `screen` bug not closing the device properly..

Comment: @stark - I don't get any improvement with using stty. It reports info indicating (to me anyway) that the port is OK.  But I may not be using it to its fullest.

Comment: So.. why does open() just stall?

Comment: Most likely the previous access changed some setting like flow control which is not being reset.

Comment: *"As far as I can tell, the open(...) command just hangs"* -- Why don't you find out for sure instead of just guess?  An **open()** syscall for a serial terminal could block if the DCD line from a modem is not asserted.

Comment: @sawdust A printf after the open() never fires when the port is locked up in this mode

Comment: I have plenty of respect for `printf` debugging, but it would be worthwhile applying a more precise technique.  Run the program in a debugger, and / or under strace to get a more detailed idea of what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Is there a better way to close the "screen" instance than the two I've been using?

That should be irrelevant if your program is made to be independent of any prior configuration and performs its own full initialization.

---

> 2) Why would "open" not return?
>
> A printf after the open() never fires when the port is locked up in this mode

An **open()** syscall for a serial terminal could block if the DCD (Data Carrier Detect) line from a modem is not asserted.
Your program can ignore the state of the DCD line during an **open()** by specifying the O_NONBLOCK option, e.g:

```
fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
```

However that option will also put the serial terminal in nonblocking mode, which will force your application to (inefficiently) poll the system for reading data instead of using the preferred event-driven capability.
Your program can revert back to blocking mode by issuing an **fcntl()** call to clear the non-blocking option, e.g.:

```
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
```

The above actually clears the five modifiable file-status flags, i.e. O_APPEND, O_ASYNC, O_DIRECT, O_NOATIME, and O_NONBLOCK flags.

---

The Linux kernel code that blocks the **open()** of the serial terminal  from continuing is the `while (1)` loop in [tty_port_block_til_ready()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/tty_port.c#L439).
Note that if the previous open of the serial terminal had set the CLOCAL termios flag, then no modem is presumed to be connected, and the check for DCD is abandoned.

Comment: I tried the O_NDELAY option but the open() call still hangs.  Are there other blocking possibilities and how can I test for them? (I'm not very familiar with running in debug - trying to do that ATM)

Comment: *"Are there other blocking possibilities..."* -- The block for DCD is intentional and explicit.  The relevant device driver (you neglect to mention exactly what you are using) could have something in its `activate()` port ops routine.  Anything else that blocks would presumably be unintentional and therefore a bug.  Note:  O_NDELAY and O_NONBLOCK are supposed to be equivalent, but can theoretically differ.  The **tty** open code specifically checks for O_NONBLOCK.

Comment: Perform some sanity tests. (1) Check if other terminal emulation programs affect your program in the same way as `screen` does.  Instead of `screen` try using `minicom` or `picocom`.  (2) Check if the state of the serial terminal after `screen` terminates affects other programs in the same way as your program hangs.  After terminating `screen`, try executing `minicom` or `picocom`.

Comment: This note is awesome.
_"Note that if the previous open of the serial terminal had set the CLOCAL termios flag, then no modem is presumed to be connected, and the check for DCD is abandoned."_